# Correct HTTP Headers for Images?

Tags: image, http, http-headers

I'm writing a web server in C#, just for the fun of it, and I am able to serve basic text files to my browser. However, when serving up an image (say, `image.png`), all browsers that I test my server on (IE, Firefox, and Chrome) show some kind of placeholder thumbnail for the image, as if the image is corrupted or invalid.

The response that I am sending to the browser looks like

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Ok
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 14580053

{image data here}
```

Am I using the correct HTTP headers? Or, if I am, why else would browsers not accept the image?

Comment: Did you compare `{image data here}` with the data of the file you're actually trying to send? You'd better try using an 1 pixel gif or an equally small file to detect subtle differences, instead of a 14 MB PNG.

Comment: Hmm... let my try that.

Comment: May I know what type of encoding should the image data be? Base64?

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur I think the data should not be encoded; rather, it should be sent as binary data in the response stream.

Comment: I was able to debug a similar issue by comparing with the response of a well-established static file server.  In my case, I learned that the mime type for svg images is `image/svg+xml`, not just `image/svg`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, figured it out... my code forgot to add an extra `\n` before the response body. It wasn't a problem with the headers at all, just incorrect response syntax.