# Why is my image not being displayed correct when loading it using readfile

Tags: php, file-get-contents, readfile

I am trying to read a thumbnail image using its file path.

```
$thumb = "/location/of/image";

$getInfo = getimagesize($thumb);
header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);
readfile($thumb);
```

The result is an image error icon.

So far I have tried;

- checking if the file exists

`var_dump(file_exists($thumb));`

result :

```
bool(true)
```

- check the getInfo to make sure it is an image:

  var_dump($getInfo);

result:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(100)
  [1]=>
  int(94)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(23) "width="100" height="94""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(8)
  ["channels"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
```

}

which appears to be correct (size mime type etc.)

. using file_get_contents($thumb) instead of file_read (a complete reach, but I had run out of ideas).

- I checked the file it is reading and I am able to download and view the image without problems, also if I call the file directly from my browser, the image displays fine.  So it doesn't look like there
- forced the file to download instead of display:

  header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

  The resultant file is not recognised by any of my image editors/views, or by a browser.  A range of errors, from "incomplete" to "unrecognized format" result, even when I set the download file name explicitly to "thumb.jpg".

I am out of ideas!  Has anyone go any other suggestions how I can debug this issue?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20247795/correct-http-headers-for-images

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$thumb = "/location/of/image";

$getInfo = getimagesize($thumb);

header('Content-type: ' . $getInfo['mime']);

ob_clean();

flush();

readfile($thumb);
```

Probably there is some white space before your opening php tag.

Comment: Ahhhh! I can't believe I didn't think to check this.  Thanks!